# Is it possible to "merge" two table borders into one another?

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have given both of my tables the same styling to create a 1px border, but the problem is that when the two tables are touching each other the bottom border from the top table and the top border from the bottom table meet and create what looks like a 2px border.

As you can see here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrUXb/)

this is the CSS I'm using to style my tables:

```
table,td, th {
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:#000;
}
```

I've tried `border-collapse:collapse;` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/yrUXb/1/ or if you don't want a 2px border between tables: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/yrUXb/2/

Comment: That just creates a similar look as "border-collapse:collapse;" but you can still see the border looks thicker where the two tables meet. I'm trying to get it to look like a 1px border all over, as if it were one table

Comment: Many ways to achieve this. Check the solution by Hashem. I think its the best

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea here is to remove all relevant top borders on every table immediately following another table.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yrUXb/10/

```css
table, td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
table + table, table + table tr:first-child th, table + table tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give style to lower table  as :

```
margin-top:-1px;
padding-top:-1px;
```

Comment: Negative value is invalid for padding

Answer (score 1):

You could override the styles with [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
table + table {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Or [general sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
table ~ table {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/yrUXb/5/)**

---

### Update

In this case, It's better to collapse the borders first:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

table, td, th {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000;
}

table + table,
table + table tr:first-child > * {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/yrUXb/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```